# Adding an object to a Crystal Report to export to excel automatically

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, subreport

I do not even know if this is possible, but I figured that if anyone would know it would be you guys.  Currently I have added an On-Demand Sub-report that takes a nicely formatted, grouped, and otherwise amazing report (It's my baby, as you can tell) and reduces it to data to fill a spreadsheet.  Since the folks who will be utilizing the spreadsheet are financial geniuses who are not that technically saavy, it has come up repeated times how inconvenient it is to have to export the report and select Data Only.  Is there a way that I can make the on-demand subreport automatically export to Data Only Excel when it is selected?  Or is there a way to add an object to this subreport that will export it to Data Only Excel?

Answer (score 0):

```
  rptDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord, Response, true, "CallPendingReport");
```

add this line into your code for export to the exel.

Comment: I do not mean to sound dense, but where inside the report would this be used?

Comment: You're not dense, he has just assumed that you're using this report in a .NET project. @Chetan, unless the question is marked with a `.NET` tag of some kind or is explicitly mentioned, it's a good bet the question pertains to CR as a standalone technology.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan.  This is CR attached to a postgreSQL db.  I only have permission to create/modify reports.